# Kill a Thread in the PropertyListener (JavaFX8)

Tags: java, multithreading, javafx, javafx-8, preemptive

I know that the actual model of Java is for collaborative Threads and that it forcing a Thread to die isn´t suppose to happens.

As `Thread.stop()` is deprecated (for the reasons listed above). I was trying to stop the thread through a BooleanProperty listener.

Here is the MCVE:

**TestStopMethod.java**

```
package javatest;
import javafx.beans.property.BooleanProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleBooleanProperty;
import javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue;
public class TestStopMethod extends Thread {
    private BooleanProperty amIdead = new SimpleBooleanProperty(false);
    public void setDeath() {
        this.amIdead.set(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        amIdead.addListener((ObservableValue<? extends Boolean> observable, Boolean oldValue, Boolean newValue) -> {
            System.out.println("I'm dead!!!");
            throw new ThreadDeath();
        });
        for(;;);
    }
}
```

**WatchDog.java**

```
package javatest;

import java.util.TimerTask;

public class Watchdog extends TimerTask {
    TestStopMethod watched;
    public Watchdog(TestStopMethod target) {
        watched = target;
    }
    @Override
    public void run() {
        watched.setDeath();
        //watched.stop(); <- Works but this is exactly what I am trying to avoid
        System.out.println("You're dead!");
    }

}
```

**Driver.java**

```
package javatest;

import java.util.*;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class Driver {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            TestStopMethod mythread = new TestStopMethod();
            Timer t = new Timer();
            Watchdog w = new Watchdog(mythread);
            t.schedule(w, 1000);
            mythread.start();
            mythread.join();
            t.cancel();
            System.out.println("End of story");
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Driver.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Which thread do you think is throwing the `ThreadDeath` error?

Comment: I thought, that if I add a listener to a the Property and change its value in the WatchDog, it would raise that exception. The code as it is now, keeps running so `mythread.join()` is never called.

Comment: It's going to be thrown from the thread which changes the property, which is the thread backing the timer instance. (If you think about it, it would basically be impossible to schedule the listener to be called on an arbitrary thread.) I think you're confusing the object which owns the method with the thread on which the method is executed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you change a property value, the listeners are invoked on the same thread from which the property was changed (just think about how you would/could implement the property classes). So in your example the `ThreadDeath` error is thrown from the thread backing the `Timer` instance, which is not really what you intended.

The proper way to terminate a thread externally (to that thread) is to set a flag, and then in the thread's implementation poll the flag at regular intervals. This is actually trickier than it sounds, because the flag has to be accessed from multiple threads, so access to it has to be properly synchronized.

Fortunately, there are some utility classes to help with this. `FutureTask`, for example, wraps a `Runnable` or `Callable` and provides `cancel()` and `isCancelled()` methods. If you are using JavaFX, then the javafx.concurrent API provides some implementations of `Callable` and `Runnable` that do this, and also provide functionality specifically for executing code on the FX Application Thread. Have a look at the [documentation for javafx.concurrent.Task](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/concurrent/Task.html) for some examples.

So, for example, you could do:

```
package javatest;
public class TestStopMethod implements Runnable {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            synchronized(this) {
                for(;;) {
                    wait(1); 
                }
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException exc) {
            System.out.println("Interrupted");
        }
    }
}
```

Watchdog.java:

```
package javatest;

import java.util.TimerTask;
import java.util.concurrent.Future;

public class Watchdog extends TimerTask {
    Future<Void> watched;
    public Watchdog(Future<Void> target) {
        watched = target;
    }
    @Override
    public void run() {
        watched.cancel(true);
        //watched.stop(); <- Works but this is exactly what I am trying to avoid
        System.out.println("You're dead!");
    }
}
```

Driver.java:

```
package javatest;

import java.util.*;
import java.util.concurrent.FutureTask;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class Driver {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            FutureTask<Void> myTask = new FutureTask<>(new TestStopMethod(), null);
            Timer t = new Timer();
            Watchdog w = new Watchdog(myTask);
            t.schedule(w, 1000);
            Thread mythread = new Thread(myTask);
            mythread.start();
            mythread.join();
            t.cancel();
            System.out.println("End of story");
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Driver.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

    }
}
```

In a JavaFX application, you might do it like this. Note that things go bad if you try to do this without the FX Application Thread running, because the `cancelled` flag in an FX `Task` must be updated on that thread.

```
package javatest;

import javafx.concurrent.Task;

public class TestStopMethod extends Task<Void> {

    @Override
    public Void call() {
        System.out.println("Calling");
        while (true) {
            if (isCancelled()) {
                System.out.println("Cancelled");
                break ;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Exiting");
        return null ;
    }
}
```

Watchdog.java:

```
package javatest;

import java.util.TimerTask;

import javafx.concurrent.Task;

public class Watchdog extends TimerTask {
    Task<Void> watched;
    public Watchdog(Task<Void> target) {
        watched = target;
    }
    @Override
    public void run() {
        watched.cancel();
        //watched.stop(); <- Works but this is exactly what I am trying to avoid
        System.out.println("You're dead!");
    }

}
```

Driver.java

```
package javatest;

import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.concurrent.Task;
import javafx.concurrent.Worker;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.TextArea;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Driver extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        try {

            TextArea console = new TextArea();
            BorderPane root = new BorderPane(console);
            Scene scene = new Scene(root, 600, 400);
            primaryStage.setScene(scene);
            primaryStage.show();

            Task<Void> myTask = new TestStopMethod();
            Timer t = new Timer();
            Watchdog w = new Watchdog(myTask);
            t.schedule(w, 1000);
            Thread mythread = new Thread(myTask);
            mythread.setDaemon(true);

            myTask.stateProperty().addListener((obs, oldState, newState) -> {
                console.appendText("State change "+oldState+" -> "+newState+"\n");
                if (oldState == Worker.State.RUNNING) {
                    t.cancel();
                    console.appendText("End of Story\n");
                }
            });
            mythread.start();

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Driver.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

    }
}
```